# MVC Form POST Not working

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have a small form which will just have two fields i.e. key(hidden) and password, and when user fills the password clicks on this submit button i need to call an action method and update something in DB. I am not able to get this working with the current code i have

**Model:-**

```
 public class AccountPasswordResetModel
    {
        public string Key { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
    }
```

**Controller**

```
    public class AccountPasswordResetController:Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return     View("~/Areas/Home/Views/AccountPasswordReset/Index.cshtml");
        }


        public ActionResult Update(AccountPasswordResetModel AccountPasswordResetModel )
        {
            return Redirect("http://www.example.org");
        }
    }
```

CSHTML :-

```
@model Verivox.Home.Presentation.Model.AccountPasswordResetModel

@using(@Html.BeginForm("Update","AccountPasswordReset",FormMethod.Post))
{
@Html.TextBoxFor(x=>x.Key)
@Html.TextBoxFor(x=>x.Password)
    <input type="submit" value="Update"/>
}
```

And the route is registered initially using Fluent Routing as below

```
var accountPasswordResetRoute = new LowercaseRoute("partners/accountVerification/{verificationKey}");
            context.MapNamedRoute(accountPasswordResetRoute.WithDefaultAction<AccountPasswordResetController>(t => t.Index()), "test");
```

So the Index actionis getting executed fine, but when i POST the form, Index() is getting executed again.

What is wrong here?

Comment: Please add your 'RouteConfig.cs'.

Comment: Did you ever resolve this issue? I'm having the same problem

Answer (score 1):

try  
  `[HttpPost]
  public ActionResult Update(AccountPasswordResetModel AccountPasswordResetModel )
        {
            return Redirect("http://www.example.org");
        }`
 Adding `[HttpPost]` before action.

**update**
edit view

```
@using(@Html.BeginForm("Update","AccountPasswordReset",FormMethod.Post))
{
 @Html.EditorFor(model =>model.Key)
 @Html.EditorFor(model =>model.Password)
    <input type="submit" value="Update"/>
}
```

or 
add into controller

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Update(string Key,string Password )
        {
            return Redirect("http://www.example.org");
        }
```

Comment: No luck behaves the same with HttpPost attribute